# Why does Yudhisthira deserve to go to heaven when he gamble his kingdom, his brother away and Draupadi being dishonor before a bunch of men?

Tags: mahabharata

And not only they suffer as a result of his gambling, but Draupadi and four Pandavas—Bhima, Arjuna, Nakula and Sahadeva perish on their way to go to heaven for various reason.
I feel like it give a bad message that gambler who pimp out his own people deserve to go to heaven.

Comment: Life is more than just one karma. Pls look into various karmas of yuddhisthir. Also, no one claims him to be perfect. He need not be to get swarg. Bhishma also had fallacies. He also attains moksha.